# Using Contextual Filters to Filter "Content: Published"

Tags: 7, views

Is there any solution to filter "Content: Published" with Contextual Filters?

Comment: Does this make sense? What is your goal?

Comment: Not out of the box and not even with Views Arguments in Filters. As asked above, what is your goal so maybe you can find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box I don't believe this is available. I have a similar use case however I am also using Workbench Moderation. I'm using the moderation state as the contextual filter and using setting a standard filter of current revision as true. This allows you to target a specific moderation state in your view, published being one of them. It could get irritating if you end up with a lot of moderation states and have to target each of them specifically but my use case requires me to get either just published, or all content regardless of published or not.